# Should I memorize the order of function arguments when learning a new module?

Tags: python, function

For example, I am now learning wxPython, specifically a class' init function:

```
__init__(self, parent, id=-1, label=EmptyString, pos=DefaultPosition,
 size=DefaultSize, style=0, name=StaticTextNameStr)
```

As a matter of good programming practice, should I memorize the order of the parameters, or just the keywords and call the function using the keywords everytime?  Is it better to do the latter for readability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memorize? No. That's what the documentation (including source code) is there for.

That being said, sometimes using keyword arguments helps the code clarity, particularly for functions which take a large number of parameters. And you should always strive to write clear code, especially in Python where the source code is meant to supplement the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the actual function signature, not just what the documentation claims it should be. Since the method is declared as `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`, the only one that matters for position is `parent`, since the others must be called by keyword anyways. You may want to follow the order of keywords given in the documentation though, just to reduce the amount of surprise when you or someone else looks at the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Mozart maybe could have memorized modern software libraries. The rest of us rely on smart IDEs with code completion, and reference docs. That being said, yes you should read over the docs to see what is there, maybe even take notes. A well-written API (e.g. Apple's libraries) is designed so that names and prototypes have meaning and stick with the reader.

e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

And so on. A good interviewer will ask you to do some of these (so that he knows you won't spend all day learning APIs) but also give you some leniency if you can't remember every parameter.